# Python3.3: ImportError with textmining-1.0

Tags: python, python-import

I installed textmining-1.0. I am having trouble importing it. When I type

```
import textmining
```

in python3.3 shell, I get the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import textmining
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\textmining\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    import stemmer
ImportError: No module named 'stemmer'
```

However I can see that stemmer.py exists in textmining-1.0 folder. Whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 7):

Converting the textmining code to python3 solved the problem for me. To do so, I manually download the text mining package from here:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/textmining/1.0

unzipped it:

```
unzip textmining-1.0.zip
```

converted the folder to python 3:

```
2to3 --output-dir=textmining-1.0_v3 -W -n textmining-1.0
```

and installed it:

```
cd textmining-1.0_v3
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Answer (score 2):

I realise that this is an old question, but I ran into the same problem, and eventually figured it out by myself:

textmining package seems to be written in python2 - so I had to do the following:

```
tar xvf textmining-1.0.tar.gz #or whatever, I forget which archive format it was
2to3 textmining-1.0
cd textmining-1.0
python setup.py install
```

Now it works like a charm on Python 3!

Comment: It did not work. I got this error message:`File "C:\Users\Win10Home\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\textmining\__init__.py", line 335, in write_csv
    f.writerow(row)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Comment: I found the bug. if you encounter the same problem until my previous comment, try to adjust the following line in the textmining.py, more specifically line 333 from `f = csv.writer(open(filename, 'wb'))` to `f = csv.writer(open(filename, 'w'))`

Answer (score 2):

I used 2to3 to convert textmining to v3, then I removed the line "import stemmer" from **init**.py. Works like a charm on Python 3.4!

Answer (score 1):

`pip install textmining3`

This package is a port to Python 3 and is based on the original. The above command installs the package without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to install the package as explained [here](http://www.christianpeccei.com/textmining/):

To install, extract the .zip file, place yourself in the `textmining-1.0` directory and run:

```
python setup.py install
```

or:

```
setup.py install
```

This works for me on Python 2.7. Not sure about Python 3.3.

Answer (score 0):

Converting the textmining code to python3 will solve it. To do so, I manually download the text mining package from here:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/textmining/1.0

unzipped it:

unzipp with **7-zip(Windows)** in the directory C:\Users\Username\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages

converted the folder to python 3:
from the command prompt(Windows)

```
2to3 --output-dir=textmining-1.0_v3 -W -n textmining-1.0
```

and installed it:

installing(Windows):

from command prompt go to the unzipped directory C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\textmining-1.0_v3

```
python3 setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

Textmining package seems to be written in python2. so it doesn't support for python 3. Here our job is to make it run for python 3. Follow the below steps

1. First manually download the text mining package [by clicking here](https://pypi.org/project/textmining/1.0/#files)
2. Unzip the file and place the unzipped folder to the anaconda directory.
   Generally Like C:\Users\sj250305\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages or (this may be little different on your computer.)
3. Convert the code to python 3 by running the following command in the command prompt(it makes the file python3 compatible.)

   ---

> 2to3 --output-dir=textmining-1.0_v3 -W -n textmining-1.0

---

4. After converting the same change directory into textmining-1.0_v3 and do
   python setup.py install(textmining-1.0_v will be created automatically and we just need to change the directory where we have our setup.py file and run the setup.py file by using the following command in command prompt)
   python setup.py install
5. After doing all of this, copy the data folder from old textmining-1.0 to new textmining-1.0_v3(optional)

Now it works fine.